# Postgres change or check datatype of all column during select into statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

```
INSERT INTO table_name( a, b, c, d) 
SELECT t1.a a, t1.b b, t1.c c, t1.d d 
FROM table_name t1
AS t(a bigint, b character varying, c numeric, d numeric)
```

But I am getting  `PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AS"`
Please anyone help me out.

Comment: Hey @klin, Thanks for your quick response, but I have like 30 columns to be checked like this while importing data, can I add all 30 columns in any simpler way?

Comment: You need to cast and alias each column separately: `select t1.a::bigint as a, ...`

Comment: If you want to change types of the columns you have to use [ALTER TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html). There is no other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a_horse_with_no_name said - cast the select list expressions.
As an alternative to numerous `alter table` statements you may do this: (1) create table with a temp name by using the select query then (2) drop the original table and finally (3) rename the one with the temp name. Still you will have to take care about constraints and indexes that may exist in the original table.

```sql
-- 1.
create table tmp_table_name as
  SELECT a::bigint as a, b::text as b, c::numeric as c, d::numeric as d
  FROM table_name;
-- 2.
drop table table_name;
-- 3.
alter table tmp_table_name rename to table_name;
```